# How can I calculate in Excel the price of something with inflation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, finance

I live in Argentina, and we have 30% anual rate of inflation.

I am paying a car also, in a plan of 84 payments. Each payment has a 27.7% of "Administrative Costs".

For example, for a `pure fee` (monthly) of `$1807`, I am paying `$2306`.

Current cost of car is `$160,000`. Each monthly fee is `$160,000/84`. (7 years).

Banks offer an annual rate of `23.4%` of interest for monthly deposits.

My goal is to know, if I will be better depositing money in Bank than paying $500 of "Administrative Costs" each month.

But I don't know what formula to use in Excel, because, for example in the last part of the Excel, it gives me that for a `$160,000` car, with `30%` inflation, in 1 year it will cost `$208,000`, but the monthly calculation ends with `$209933.87`, so, I think I'm doing something wrong in the formula.

https://docs.zoho.com/sheet/published.do?rid=12cbm43aa83422b1c4c9eb327fdde40b43d1b

Comment: out of the topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single event of $30\%$ inflation, after one year the price goes from $160,000$ to $208,000$ as you say.  If the inflation is $2.5\%$ per month and you apply it every month, in one year the $160,000$ goes to $160,000(1.025)^{12}\approx 215182.21$  The difference represents the effect of [compound interest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest).  Normally annual inflation should take account of the compound interest, so if it were truly $2.5\%$ every month the annual value would be $1.025^{12}\approx 34.49\%$.  I didn't check your spreadsheet-without some explanation it is quite difficult.

Comment: So, how can I convert a 30% annual inflation into monthly inflation, and get the same result?

Comment: You are looking for $(1+x)^{12}=1.3, x=1.3^{(1/12)}-1, x\approx .0221$, so it is about $2.21\%$ per month to get $30\%$ per year.